# Process doesn't finish after closing a window

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, ubuntu, tkinter

I'm building a chat app on python using sockets and tkinter. Everything works correctly on Windows, but when i try to run it on Ubuntu some problems occurred. If i try to close an application window, process doen't finish and i need to kill it to finish the programm.

I think it might be because of threads or something goes wrong with sockets connections. I've tried to write some code to fix it but problem still the same.

This code snippet is for closing client side window. It works on Windows and on Ubuntu don't.

```
def close_connection(self):
        self.is_receive_message = False
        self.client_side.close()
        self.destroy()
        client.quit()
```

There i try to close server side. I create thread for every client and when window is closing i try to end all of thread and finish all of the connection. Again, on Widows everything is OK, while on Ubuntu doesn't.

```
def quit_server(self):
    self.accepting_connection = False
    for client in self.clients:
        client.close()
        client.is_receive_message = False
        self.threads[client].join()

    self.server.close()
    server.quit()
```

Full code can be found here: https://github.com/Tynianov/chat_app

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post a [mcve] not a link